# code errors bad operand type for unary -: 'str'

Tags: python, numpy

I am writing a code where I create noise on an S-curve, the code works because I tried it with real values and it was working just fine.

I tried to make it more complex by creating two inputs that the user can decide, which would be the noise and the steepness of the curve.

Here is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z)) #Function for the S-curve

noise=input('Please, insert here a number that will define how big the noise of the curve will be (the bigger the number, the bigger the noise.): ')
steepness=input('Please, insert here a number that will define the steepness of the curve (The bigger the number, the steeper the steep): ')

x = np.arange(-steepness, steepness, (2*steepness)/1000)  # x values
n = noise * np.random.random(x.shape) - 0.1 # noise for each value of the sigmoid
y = sigmoid(x) + n  # S-curve plus noise
print(y)
plt.plot(x, y, marker='*')
plt.xlabel('X-axis')
plt.ylabel('Y-axis')
plt.title('S-curve with noise')
plt.show()
```

But with this code I have two errors...

The first one is this one : TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'

The second one is this one : ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')

The other code without the inputs that works just fine is this one :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z)) #Function for the S-curve

x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.01)  # x values
n = 0.2 * np.random.random(x.shape) - 0.1 # noise for each value of the sigmoid
y = sigmoid(x) + n  # S-curve plus noise
print(y)
plt.plot(x, y, marker='*')
plt.xlabel('X-axis')
plt.ylabel('Y-axis')
plt.title('S-curve with noise')
plt.show()
```

Can you help me figure out what the problem is please?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the inputs to floating point numbers by using `float`:

```
noise=float(input('Please, insert here a number that will define how big the noise of the curve will be (the bigger the number, the bigger the noise.): '))
steepness=float(input('Please, insert here a number that will define the steepness of the curve (The bigger the number, the steeper the steep): '))
```

Without including this, Python will think the variables are strings, not numbers.

Comment: Oops, fixed @jjramsey